# Why do firefox 4 and evolution always open maximized in Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, evolution, firefox

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Prevent Unity from auto-maximizing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45270/prevent-unity-from-auto-maximizing)
>   [How to keep programs from launching maximized? 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40571/how-to-keep-programs-from-launching-maximized-11-04)

Why do Firefox 4 and Evolution always open maximized in Unity? Even after you close the program windowed. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3):

There are two things to consider there.

- All applications which opens with a initial size > 75% of the screen area will get automaximzed.
- There is a known bugs about some applications, even closed fullscreen (fullscreen and not maximized), where they can't be restored easily. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/765422

Answer (score 0):

Some applications will always open maximized in Unity. It's something to do with their initial size: if they take up more then X of the screen, they will be maximized (I'm not sure what's the value of X though).